# Open image from ALAsset representation in default Photos app

Tags: assets, uiapplication, uidocumentinteraction, openurl

How can I open an image obtained from the Assets Library in the default 'Photos' app on iPhone? Ideally this should work without temporally storing a second instance of the image in my app's document folder.

I tried the following but there is no URL hook for "assets-library://":

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=523360F1-385B-4E2D-8DF0-DA893AC631CE&ext=JPG"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Perhaps the better way is to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but it seems it would require saving the image to my documents folder first, which takes a few seconds on my device.

Thank you for any help!

- Klaus

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe iOS supports a URL scheme for opening specific photos in the photos app. If you want such a scheme to exist, the best you can do is file a radar.